# How truncate a table in MySQL that is using ManyToMany field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, many-to-many

I have a table in MySQL which have a ManyToMany field and I want truncate the table, but when I try it, I obtain the following error:

`ERROR 1701 (42000): Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint ...`

I'm using Symfony with Doctrine but if it is possible, I'm interested in learn how to do it through console

```
class Project {

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Shipping", mappedBy="projects")
  **/
  private $employee;
}

class Employee{

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="employee")
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="middle_table")
  **/
  protected $projects;
}
```

Comment: Please provide related entities

Comment: I updated it my question

Comment: Through Symfony's console or MySQL's one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To truncate a table with a ManyToMany relationship, you'll need to temporarily disable foreign key checks, truncate the related tables, and then enable foreign key checks again. Since you want to do this through the console, you can follow these steps using MySQL commands:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; -- Disable foreign key checking.
TRUNCATE TABLE forums;
TRUNCATE TABLE dates;
TRUNCATE TABLE remarks;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; -- Enable foreign key checking.
```

Keep in mind that truncating tables will remove all data from the tables, so be careful when executing these commands. Make sure to backup your data if necessary.

If you're using Doctrine in Symfony, you can achieve the same result by executing raw SQL queries using the Doctrine connection. However, since you're interested in using the console, the above MySQL commands should work for your use case.

Comment: Yes, I have two different classes and an intermediate table. But how can I truncate the table? In my case, I want truncate my `projects` table

Comment: Okay, perfect. Thanks you so much. It has sense truncate first child tables and later parent tables

Answer (score 0):

Now your foreign key in middle_table does not allow you to delete records from Projects table. In other words you have a link to Project in middle_table, it does not give a chance to delete row from Project. So you should change definition of your foreign key to allow deletion, you can set to null the link or make cascade delete. I prefer second option, so change annotation to following, it should allow you to delete rows in Projects table, it also will delete link to Project in middle_table.

```
class Project {

  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Shipping", mappedBy="projects", cascade={"remove"})
  **/
  private $employee;
}
```

Documentation:
[Doctrine association mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)
[mysql foreign key contraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_foreign_key_constraint)